# How to use external javascript file into an ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working in a new web portal. So far using the express and node.js i have a server and some ejs files.

The body structure of my site is like this:

```
   - node modules
   - public
      --javascript
         ---myScript.js
   -views
      --pages
        ---index.ejs
        ---about.ejs
      --partials
        ---footer.ejs
        ---head.ejs
        ---header.ejs
    package.json
    server.js
```

***server.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set the view engine to ejs

app.get('/', function(req, res) {res.render('pages/index');}); // index page 
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {    res.render('pages/about');}); // about page 

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Portal is listening to port 8080 ');
```

***and the index.ejs***

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<% include ../partials/head %>
</head>
<body class="container">
<header>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
</header>
<main>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>MyPortal</h1>
        <button>Press</button>
    <% var test = 101; %>
    </div>
</main>
    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In the partials i want to call and use an external .js file `/public/javascript/myScript.js` so i can use variable from it in my ejs page or send a variable.

my js file have a simple function (just to see if it's working) that print in console if the button (in index.ejs) is pressed.

***myScript.js***

```
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function () {
  console.log("button pressed");
   });
  });
```

I'm trying to call the external js in head.ejs (*or in index.ejs*)...

```
<!-- views/partials/head.ejs -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MyPortal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>body    { padding-top:50px; } </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/pubic/javascript/myScript.js"></script>
```

but i'm getting this error (in console)

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/pubic/javascript/myScript.js”.
```

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: `public` was mistyped `pubic`

Comment: yes i just show it... i change it to "public" but the problem remains

Comment: Could you open the url of the script in your browser and see if it shows anything?

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` should not be used in HTML 5. It has no purpose other than to allow you to make a typo and break your script.

Comment: niko try to add this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` after setting the view engine. You also need to require path module `var path = require('path');`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to load **client-side** JavaScript, the fact you are using EJS is irrelevent. A standard HTML script element is all you need in the template, and you have that.

You do, however, need to provide a URL (with the src attribute) that the web browser can use to fetch the script … and your script has no URL.

You are getting the message *Loading failed for the with source `“http://localhost:8080/pubic/javascript/myScript.js”.`* because it is a 404 Error.

You should use the [static module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to provide the JS file with a URL.

```
app.use("/public", express.static('public'))
```

Comment: i understand what you are saying. But even using the "app.use("/public", express.static('public'))" in my server.js file i still see the error that the script cant be loaded

Comment: @Nikos Kalantas looks like you're using jQuery. If so link the jquery cdn in your html (preferably at the end of the body) and your script tag after the jquery link tag (important)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your server.js file,
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public");

And to link the js file with your ejs file,